# Fixed Header flickers in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at [this](http://oopthemes.com/declat/) WordPress theme, if you scroll the page in chrome or safari, the page flickers.

Please make the height of the browser smaller so that you can scroll, I am using the below code to add `narrow-header` class to my `header-wrap`.

```
( function( $ ) {
  var header = $(".header-wrap");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 200) {
          header.removeClass('normal-header').addClass("narrow-header fadeIn animated");
      } else {
          header.removeClass("narrow-header fadeIn animated").addClass('normal-header');
      }
});

} )( jQuery );
```

And this is the CSS I am using:

```css
.narrow-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because when the page scrolls beyond 200px from top , the js code adding the class `.narrow-header` which has `position: fixed;` . This changes the scroll top offset and it becomes less than 200 . Then the js code again adds the class normal-header ... the cycle repeats and the page appears to be flickering .

To overcome this you need to set some min height to the parent element which maintains the height of the webpage and the scroll position no matter what is the positioning of the header . If your header directly comes under body you need to wrap it inside a parent element .

```
<body>
    <header class="main-header">
       <div class="header-wrap">
          <nav>
               .......header navigation.......
          </nav>
       </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

1. The CSS way - 
   Put the height of the header element to its parent element .

   ```
   .main-header {
       min-height : 100px ; /*assuming your header is have height of 100px*/
   }
   ```
2. The JS Way

   ```
   var header = $(".header-wrap");
   header.parent().css('min-height' , header.height());
   ```

Hope this helps .